# Delete both children and parent SQL records

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I wish to delete a child of a given id, and also delete the parent if the child's parent no longer has any more children after the child is deleted. CASCADE DELETE works great for deleting the children of a deleted parent, however, this is not my intent.  Foreign key constraints are enforced, and I do not wish to temporarily disable.  I would rather not use a trigger or stored procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parents (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS children (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  parentsId INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_children_parents_idx (parentsId ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_children_parents
    FOREIGN KEY (parentsId)
    REFERENCES parents (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Sample Data

```
parents
id data
1  foo1
2  foo2

children

id parentId data
1         1 bar1
2         2 bar3
3         2 bar3
```

For instance, with the above data, deleting child #1 should delete parent #1, however, deleting child #2 or (not and) #3 should not delete parent #2.

I can do it in three queries (1. get parentsId, 2. delete child, 3. delete parent if it doesn't have any children), however, feel it could/should be better.

I was thinking something similar to the following, however, it is not correct.

```
DELETE c, p FROM children c
LEFT OUTER JOIN parents p ON p.id=c.parentsId AND c.id!=123
WHERE c.id=123 AND p.id IS NULL;
```

How can this be performed in one or a maximum of two queries?

Comment: the problem with 1 query is that when deleting children and parent at the same time, query do not know if there are any more children, beacuase nothing was yet deleted.

Comment: @Whencesoever  Agree unless if maybe child is deleted in a subquery, and child id is passed out of the subquery?

Comment: the best bet really is a trigger. Since mysql doesn't have common table expressions, the only way I can think of doing it with two queries would have very poor performance. Anway, why don't you post your show create tables and some data?

Comment: @e4c5  Yeah, I could do a trigger, but I always forget I created one, and confuse myself why something happened.  Structure and sample data provided.

Comment: any reason why that is no action on delete?

Comment: @e4c5  Nope!  Just forgot.  I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There's nothing wrong with your three step design.**

This design is straightforward, simple, and effective.  There's no reason to suspect that it will be prohibitively inefficient.

There are ways to do it in fewer steps, but they all involve doing "something complicated" and thus have the downside of being harder to develop and less intuitive.

You may "feel it could/should be better" (and it's great to explore alternatives), but I don't see anything better than your proposed design (absent some specific issue, like unacceptable performance).

Comment: Thanks Dan,  I am satisfied.  I just don't like to do something when it could/should be done better.  I will keep it as it is, and sleep well at night.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1032531 it's great be driven to do things better.  The trick is to know when that drive is leading you to over-design and stop yourself (I know because I've made that mistake on occasion :) ).

Comment: Only on occasion?  I think I do it all the time!  But eventually, I discover the error of my ways :)

Comment: `There are ways to do it in fewer steps` - which ones? Yes, I want to shoot myself in the foot, so could you please give me the gun? Preferably, not like this: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; DELETE ...; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`. I mean, is there a way to specify the order of removal? Like "first, remove the rows from the child table, then remove the rows from the parent one"?